# Is there any Unix window manager that looks like it is from a sci fi movie?

Tags: unix, window-manager

I woke up today with a weird desire to make my laptop look like those sci-fi movies where a hacker/IT guy can save the world using just a macbook ( -.- ).

Anyway on all those movies you can notice beautiful themes that make them look like they really know what they're doing. I won't say any more because I am sure you know what I mean.

How can I do that? I didn't find a window manager that looks like that.

A random (windows) desktop theme I found that begins to resemble what I want is:

[image: cool desktop background *.*]

I am talking about **useless** logs on desktop, distracting lights and random things rotating. If someone knows something similar to this idea, please tell me!

Comment: I tried doing this a couple of times over the years. Mostly I found that the stuff just got in my way when I was trying to actually use the computer, gave up, and went back to a fairly normal looking desktop.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah you are right. But I already have a serious desktop computer. I want to make my laptop cool looking! Just for fun. You said you tried it over the years. What did you do?

Comment: I feel like you're most likely to find desktop themes that match what you're looking for if you look for Fluxbox or Openbox configs. So, do image searches for stuff like "Fluxbox Tron" or "Openbox Matrix" and see what the webpages for the screenshots you like say.

Answer (score 1):

Conky is a very popular system monitor for unix-like operating systems, it can display a lot of system information.

http://conky.sourceforge.net/

You might be interested in tiling window managers, they are very popular with unix powerusers, popular ones are `awesome` and `i3`.

http://awesome.naquadah.org/

Answer (score 0):

I used to use LiteStep for this back in late middle school to early high school (Early 2000's). I haven't kept up on the status of the project but it was pretty sweet for Windows XP back in the day. The logs, btw, can be incredibly handy... Always loved the networking ones...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows